# App resumed from Background, nil property of NSManagedObject

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, nscoder

**Conditions**

- Getting a notification (txt message)
- or Opening/Closing Notification Center
- or Switch to another app, come back

Basically, the app comes back from background for a short period.

**Issue**

Layout is ok, but some of my properties that I get from CoreData are empty after resuming from Background. This issue is there on pretty much all of my view controllers.

**The project**

This is an app that has a main tabbar controller, with two navigationcontrollers within the tabs and maybe two levels of viewcontrollers, that have themselves child UIViews (that use some of the informations). The back-end is made of Parse and CoreData.

**The weird part**

Back from background -> properties are ok on viewWillAppear (Create a backup of the id) -> they are nil seconds after -> I need to manually get them back (from the ID I just stored)

Here is a screenshot, when putting a break point within a function called every 5sec to check the current time ([link to bigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcNTX.png)) :[image]

**What I did**

NSCoder implemented for state restoration and every view controllers have a restoration ID, however it doesn't get called when app is becoming active. I don't think NSCoder is the issue here since from the documentation it is used when the OS will kill it on its own, or a force quit from the user.

I tried to manually refresh the content in the appropriate ViewControllers from NSNotificationCenter if the NSManagedObjects are nil, but it is not future-proof, and is never the same logic on each view.

Any thoughts? Thank you!

My AppDelegate :

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"Will Resign Active");
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"Entered Background");  
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"Will enter Foreground");
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"needsRefresh" object:self userInfo:nil]; // Helpful in some viewcontrollers to save variables that are not nil.

    [PF_FBSession.activeSession handleDidBecomeActive];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSLog(@"Will Terminate");
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint on the setter for `_booking` and see what is nil'ing it out?  It's hard to know what is going on since you aren't showing any of the implementation code or if you have any notifications sent in `applicationWillEnterForeground` etc that could affect this.

Comment: @iWasRobbed Edited! My delegate is pretty much empty, I'll edit again with more related code

Comment: I'm having the same issue in a Swift project. Anyone solve this issue?

Comment: @nh32rg I found the issue, posted the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those finding this thread, here is the solution I found.

My issue and answer was specific to my project.

I had another controller, the one that takes care of all my database connections, that was listening to applicationDidBecomeActive.
This was calling up a refresh of my data, but also a "cleanup", that was deleting/editing some NSManagedObjects, then saving.

Conclusion : the memory address wasn't the same, the object wasn't considered the same, and therefore was empty on my current page.

I fixed it by stopping cleaning up on each AppDidBecomeActive, but move that logic to AppDidFinishLaunching instead.

Hope that helped!

Comment: I was doing something similar that I had forgotten about and your tip reminded me! Thanks for the help.